# AngularJS/JavaScript - How to rename an array key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an application that reads an excel file, and displays its contents in an html table.

These elements are in an array called "AgendaItems".

There are 2 files the user can read, each is formatted with some differences.
Both have 3 columns.

File 1: AgendaItem, LegistarId, Title
File 2: Agenda #, File #, Title

I am able to read the file and populate the array $scope.AgendaItens with the contents of either file, depending what the user selects.

My problem is that before making these modifications to accept a second file with a different format, I used:

```
<td scope="row">{{ai.AgendaItem}}</td>
<td>{{ai.LegistarID}}</td>
```

When processing the new file, now the array contains: Agenda #, and File #, which are equivalent to AgendaItem, and LegistarID respectively.

Is there a way to, in the HTML choose which value to display? for example, if array has AgendaItem, display AgendaItem, if array has Agenda #, display Agenda #?

Or, is it possible to rename a the name of a key, from Agenda # to AgendaItem and from File # to LegistarID?

Please let me know if I need to post more details, more code in order for me to be able to get help.

Thank you in advance,
Erasmo

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript array.map extension ? May be better for later reading the code.

Source data

```
var source = [{"Agenda #":"1","File #":"file1.xls"}]
```

Map it for cleaner usage

```
var maped = source.map(function(p) {
    return {"AgendaItem":p["Agenda #"], "LegistarID":p["File #"]}
})
```

Other wise you have to use Object[fieldName] usage in html.(not suggesting to do so) like; ng-if="expression"

```
  < ... ng-if='data["Agenda #"]' > {{data["Agenda #"]}}
```

...

Comment: Also please do not try to read excel files in js.. copy and paste works very nicely.
for inspire                                                                      
       https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pasteultimate?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts